# Migrating to keycloak for an app that uses spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, keycloak

I'm looking for steps to keycloak for an Spring MVC app that uses spring security currently.

I wanted to use keycloak in [Sitewhere](https://github.com/sitewhere/sitewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is so simple if I would have read keycloak's document fully:). Any how here are the steps that I followed while migrating to keycloak in [Sitewhere](http://sitewhere.org/) .

1. Follow the steps as given in keycloak doc for [spring-security](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/ch08.html#spring-security-adapter)
2. Add the dependency to sitewhere-core & sitewhere-web pom.xml as stated in [adapter installation](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/ch08.html#d4e1219)
3. Also add the jboss-logging dependency in sitewhere-web's pom.xml since, keycloak spring adapter has a hardcode dependency for jboss-logging.
4. Modify applicationcontext.xml so that it can uses keycloak for both web & api, following the sample for api

   ```
   <sec:http pattern="/api/**"  entry-point-ref="keycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint">
   <sec:custom-filter ref="keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
   <sec:custom-filter ref="keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
   ```
5. Modify LoginManager.java as follows

   ```
   public static IUser getCurrentlyLoggedInUser() throws SiteWhereException {
   Authentication KeyCloakAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   if (KeyCloakAuth == null) {
       throw new SiteWhereSystemException(ErrorCode.NotLoggedIn, ErrorLevel.ERROR,
               HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
   }

   KeycloakAccount  keyAccount = ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) KeyCloakAuth).getAccount();

   String username = keyAccount.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdToken().getPreferredUsername();
   String password = "";

   IUser user = SiteWhere.getServer().getUserManagement().authenticate(username, password);
   List<IGrantedAuthority> auths =
           SiteWhere.getServer().getUserManagement().getGrantedAuthorities(user.getUsername());
   SitewhereUserDetails details = new SitewhereUserDetails(user, auths);


   Authentication auth = new SitewhereAuthentication(details, password);

   if (!(auth instanceof SitewhereAuthentication)) {
       throw new SiteWhereException("Authentication was not of expected type: "
               + SitewhereAuthentication.class.getName() + " found " + auth.getClass().getName()
               + " instead.");
   }
   return (IUser) ((SitewhereAuthentication) auth).getPrincipal();
   ```

   }
6. Since, we have migrated our authentication to keycloak and for the fact that we will not get credentials of user in siterwhere it's better to void the code related to password validation in authentication method of IUserManagement. Following is the sample from MongoUserManagement.java

   ```
   public IUser authenticate(String username, String password) throws SiteWhereException {
   if (password == null) {
       throw new SiteWhereSystemException(ErrorCode.InvalidPassword, ErrorLevel.ERROR,
               HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
   }
   DBObject userObj = assertUser(username);
   String inPassword = SiteWherePersistence.encodePassoword(password);
   User match = MongoUser.fromDBObject(userObj);
   //nullify authentication since we are using keycloak
   /*if (!match.getHashedPassword().equals(inPassword)) {
       throw new SiteWhereSystemException(ErrorCode.InvalidPassword, ErrorLevel.ERROR,
               HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
   }*/

   // Update last login date.
   match.setLastLogin(new Date());
   DBObject updated = MongoUser.toDBObject(match);
   DBCollection users = getMongoClient().getUsersCollection();
   BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(MongoUser.PROP_USERNAME, username);
   MongoPersistence.update(users, query, updated);

   return match;}
   ```
7. Make sure you have respective roles for the users in keycloak that are more specific to sitewhere.
8. Change your home page so that it redirects to keycloak for authentication purpose. Following is the sample for redirection:

   ```
       Tracer.start(TracerCategory.AdminUserInterface, "login", LOGGER);
   try {
       Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       data.put("version", VersionHelper.getVersion());
       String keycloakConfig = environment.getProperty("AUTHSERVER_REDIRECTION_URL");          
       if (SiteWhere.getServer().getLifecycleStatus() == LifecycleStatus.Started) {
           return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+keycloakConfig);
       } else {
           ServerStartupException failure = SiteWhere.getServer().getServerStartupError();
           data.put("subsystem", failure.getDescription());
           data.put("component", failure.getComponent().getLifecycleError().getMessage());
           return new ModelAndView("noserver", data);
       }
   } finally {
       Tracer.stop(LOGGER);
   }
   ```